# Getting an Insomnia Error while using Git Sync and Bitbucket server

Tags: bitbucket-server, insomnia

Our team is trying to setup a repository to share all the API tests. We decided to host the repository ourself with Bitbucket Server, but end up with an error while using the Git Sync function in Insomnia. We followed the documentation to get the authentication token (HTTP access token) and tried different user/author names. Any suggestions on how we might fix this problem?

Error code while trying to Sync:

```
HttpError: HTTP Error: 404 
        at GitRemoteHTTP.discover (/Applications/Insomnia.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/isomorphic-git/index.cjs:6665:13)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
        at async _fetch (/Applications/Insomnia.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/isomorphic-git/index.cjs:7315:22)
        at async _clone (/Applications/Insomnia.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/isomorphic-git/index.cjs:7692:42)
        at async Object.clone (/Applications/Insomnia.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/isomorphic-git/index.cjs:7815:12)
        at async GP (file:///Applications/Insomnia.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/index.c4312761.js:1886:6051)
        at async gz.onSubmitEdits [as _onSubmitEdits] (file:///Applications/Insomnia.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/index.c4312761.js:1895:11562)
```

Comment: 404 is "not found", indicating a bad URL. Check whatever has generated the URL, and check your own server's logs to see if you got a request and if so, for what URL path. (This isn't a Git issue, at least not yet, since it's up to the client—which in this case is insomnia, not Git—to provide the URL, and up to the server to answer it. Also, note that the tag info for [tag:api] says "don't use this tag"...)

Comment: Hi @MHV, this is a known issue, https://github.com/Kong/insomnia/issues/2220, I noticed your comment there just now. We'll keep you and the community updated in the issue.

Comment: @FilipeFreire our team fixed it by using the early access (beta) when the fix was merged. Thanks a lot for the great open-source software :)